# What should be ideal hardware specifications for a Parachain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rococo, relay-chain

We are working on a parachain and planning to integrate with Polkadot relay chain.

When we deployed our parachain on testnet and tried to integrate with Rococo, we realised that less than 500 GB and 8 GB RAM is not enough.

What should be ideal hardware specifications for a mainnet Parachain to connect with Polkadot relay chain?

Can someone please help me to provide this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on which type of node:

- For a collator, you need to fit requirements of Substrate benchmark of the parachain. The most important will be single core CPU performance and disk read/write speed (NVMe disk is almost mandatory).
- For RPC nodes, you need bigger disk space to run as archive node + capacity to process requests if the RPC is public (and this all depends on traffic)
- For a bootnode, you also need to run as archive but it will not compute a lot, just sync.

8 Gb RAM should generally be enough for non RPC node, I generally recommend a minimum of 8 core CPU @4.5Ghz with NVMe SSD drive of 500 Gb.
Good connectivity is also very important.

But in purely sync function, it can be much less, for example I'm running an Astar archive node on a Raspberry Pi4 with 2Gb RAM, it is synced correctly.

Comment: Thanks. For RPC Node, is 16 GB RAM and SSD drive of 1 TB enough?

Comment: In most cases yes, but as soon as you reach more than 1M requests you're going to want to have several RPCs behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the [Polkadot reference hardware](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#reference-hardware) to get an impression about the minimum advised hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a compiled with parachain node runtime-benchmarks feature you can run a neat command that will show you whether your hardware meets the requirements for a good parachain.

`cargo run --release --features runtime-benchmarks -- benchmark machine`